# Position left floating div from content and not left of page

Tags: html, css

In my web page, I have a div that stays static on the left even as the user scrolls.

This is the CSS for the div:

```
.floatingDiv
{
    position:fixed; 
    top:300px;
    left:70px;  
    padding:16px;
}
```

As you can see, I am positioning the div relative to the top left corner of the page.

However, my main content is only about 1000px wide, and I want to position this div from the left edge of my content rather than the left edge of the screen. At my resolution of 1440x900, the div currently is placed exactly halfway between the left edge of the screen and the left edge of the content, but if someone is using a wide-screen monitor, this floating div is rather far away from the content.

Comment: use jquery to get the position of the content, and then apply that position to .floatingDiv

Comment: i'm not using jquery so far for the site and wouldn't want to just for this. Could I not just use Javascript to achieve the same? I'm trying to do this but it doesn't work: `document.getElementById('floatingdiv').style.left = (screen.width-1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFloatingDiv()
    {
        document.getElementById('floatdiv').style.left = (screen.width - 1200)/2 + 'px';
    }
    </script>
<body onload="setFloatingDiv()">
```

Here's a better way to do it so it works even if the window isn't maximized:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function setSidebar()
 {
    if (document.getElementById('main_container').offsetLeft > 150)
        {
            document.getElementById('floatdiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('floatdiv').style.left = (document.getElementById('main_container').offsetLeft - 150) + 'px';
        }       
        else //not enough space for it. Hide it
            document.getElementById('floatdiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
</script>
```

I call this function `onload` and `onresize`

Answer (score 0):

From Sitepoint: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position

The value fixed generates an absolutely positioned box that’s positioned relative to the initial containing block *(normally the viewport).* The position can be specified using one or more of the properties top, right, bottom, and left. In the print media type, the element is rendered on every page.

So your div should go inside your content container, then ensure you have position:relative on the content container so it acts as the reference for positioning for all child elements. This is the same for position:absolute.

```
<div style='position:relative'>
my main container
  <div style='position:fixed;top:300px;left:70px;'>this is my fixed element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually want the floating div n pixels to the left of the left edge of my content div, so it would technically by outside that div.

Comment: try this but with a negative pixel value e.g. -70px;

Answer (score 0):

you can create another wrapper, wraps all the elements you talked above.

put the floating div inside of the big wrapper

online demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/wfhpb/

another demo link: http://noslog.com/1440.html